# How to flush php curl's dns cache?

Tags: php, curl, dns

PHP Curl has a dns cache, that is enabled by default:

CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

I can't seem to find any resources on how to clear this cache (aside from apache restart).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to manually clean DNS cache from PHP. But you can use [`CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT.html)

> Pass a long, this sets the timeout in seconds. Name resolves will be
>   kept in memory and used for this number of seconds. Set to zero to
>   completely disable caching, or set to -1 to make the cached entries
>   remain forever. By default, libcurl caches this info for 60 seconds.

You can set option to `0` for next request to force curl's DNS cache to be flushed